# Exclude elements from group in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Imagine a set of rules like the ones shown below:

```
span, div { color: red; }    
span { background: white; }
div { background: black; }
```

Is it possible to wrap them under 1 SCSS rule? Something in the form of:

```
span, div {
    & { color: red; }    
    &:not(div) { background: white;}    
    &:not(span) { background: black; }
}
```

Unfortunately an approach like this could very easily get quite large. So I'm hoping for an SCSS implementation of the code shown at the top but without the use of `:not(<every other selector>)`.

Preferably something looking like (invalid code):

```
span, div {
    & { color: red; }    
    &(span) { background: white;}    
    &(span) { background: black; }
}
```

Comment: Do you need this only for this specific case?

Comment: @Arkellys No this is just an example. I've had multiple cases where I had 5 different selectors that share 8 lines of code and some of those selectors need a few more rules.

Comment: Why do you want to wrap them inside a common selector instead of keeping them separated?

Comment: But with the code you are asking for, aren't you repeating the selectors anyway ?

Comment: @Arkellys Didnt say I wasn't repeating the selectors. I said it was more tidy since all of the rules concerning those parts are together

Comment: I see... Well, I made a mixin that might solve your problem, but it seems a bit over complicated for such a simple thing. I will post it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to do what you want this way *(but I may be wrong)*.

The code below achieve the result you are looking for but uses a map, a `@mixin` and `@extend` instead of a single selector. Maybe it's a bit too complex for want you want to achieve but I hope it can help:

```
@mixin setSelectors($elements) {
  %commonProperties {
    @content;
  }

  @each $selector, $properties in $elements {
    #{$selector} {
      @extend %commonProperties;
      @each $property, $value in $properties {
        #{$property}: #{$value};
      }
    }
  }
}

@include setSelectors((
  span: (background: white),
  div: (background: black)
)) {
  color: red; // Common properties
}
```

Will return:

```
div, span { color: red; }
span { background: white; }
div { background: black; }
```

The first argument is a map containing all your selectors and their specific properties. The `@content` of the `@mixin` contains shared properties.
If you need to add a selector that doesn't have any specific property, you can add it to the map with `null` as key. Such as:

```
@include setSelectors((
  span: (background: white),
  div: (background: black),
  i: null
)) {
  color: red;
}
```

However, this solution doesn't allow nested selectors so I believe that separating the selectors is the best way to go.

Comment: I am afraid this is a bit more complicated than what I was hoping. It also seems be less flexible since it doesn't allow nested selectors. Though I am very grateful for the time you put in to show and explain this to me

Comment: I agree that it is not flexible at all. I hope someone else will have a better idea. (: